# Wordpress add_action("wp_insert_comment", array($this, "myfunction"),1); does nothing

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Hi I'm creating a wordpress plugin which I want to pop up a window any time a comment is inserted in a wordpress blogpost. Event when I put in a simple PHP code in my called function of echo "This is a test"; and then post a comment in my Wordpress dev environment, nothing happens. Is there something I'm missing as I'm not able to resolve this?

See code below;

```
if (!class_exists("tweet_blog_comment")
    class tweet_blog_comment
      {
        function __construct()
            {
               add_action("wp_insert_comment", array($this, "twitter_window"), 1);
            }

        function twitter_window()
            {
               echo 
                    "<script>
                        mywindow = window.open('http://www.twitter.com', '', 'width=500, height=500');
                        mywindow.focus();
                    </script>";
            }
      }

if (class_exists("tweet_blog_comments"))
    {
        $tweet_comment = new tweet_blog_comment();
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to set it up to do it from a modal window (popup function)?  And please list your code as it is unclear.  Have you tried this? http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_comment

Comment: You cant just add an echo and expect it to show up.  you have to do a function that will run in the background when wp_insert_comment is sent.

Comment: Check out this plugin code and you might get some inspiration  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/commentluv/installation/

Comment: Thanks guys, have not had access to email for over a week. I'll take your comments on board and hopefully will make some progress

Comment: I've modified my function so that a twitter window is displayed any time a comment is added to a blog post but still nothing happens when I add a comment to a blog post. What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: you may get some ideas from this link http://wordpress.org/support/topic/thank-you-popup-after-leaving-a-comment